# Why can't heroku install nokogiri 1.6.5, on bamboo stack, using ruby 1.9.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

On my laptop, my version of ruby is:

```
$ ruby -version
ruby 1.9.3p551 (2014-11-13 revision 48407) [x86_64-darwin14.0.0]
```

and my version of rails is:

```
$ ./bin/rails -v
Rails 3.2.15
```

My Gemfile has an unversioned reference to nokogiri:

```
$ grep nokogiri Gemfile
gem "nokogiri"
```

but my Gemfile.lock shows this:

```
nokogiri (1.6.5)
  mini_portile (~> 0.6.0)
```

I'm on the legacy bamboo stack:

```
$ heroku info | grep -i stack
Stack:         bamboo-mri-1.9.2
```

and when I push to heroku (using git-ssh transport):

```
$ git push heroku master
```

the deployment bombs when it reaches the nokogiri dependency:

```
   ...
   Installing nokogiri (1.6.5) with native extensions /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:483:in `rescue in block in build_extensions': ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. (Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError)

   /usr/ruby1.9.2/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
   *** extconf.rb failed ***
   Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
   necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
   details.  You may need configuration options.

   Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/ruby1.9.2/bin/ruby
    --help
    --clean
   /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:445:in `try_compile': wrong number of arguments (3 for 2) (ArgumentError)
    from extconf.rb:77:in `block in add_cflags'
    from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:481:in `with_cflags'
    from extconf.rb:76:in `add_cflags'
    from extconf.rb:323:in `<main>'
   checking if the C compiler accepts ... 

   Gem files will remain installed in /tmp/build_8908ccf0104d2f6073466c3fe2186d76/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.6.5 for inspection.
   Results logged to /tmp/build_8908ccf0104d2f6073466c3fe2186d76/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.6.5/ext/nokogiri/gem_make.out
    from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:486:in `block in build_extensions'
    from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:446:in `each'
    from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:446:in `build_extensions'
    from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:198:in `install'
    from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/source.rb:95:in `install'
    from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/installer.rb:55:in `block in run'
    from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in `block in each'
    from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in `each'
    from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in `each'
    from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/installer.rb:44:in `run'
    from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/installer.rb:8:in `install'
    from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/cli.rb:225:in `install'
    from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in `run'
    from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:118:in `invoke_task'
    from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:246:in `dispatch'
    from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:389:in `start'
    from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.7/bin/bundle:13:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/ruby1.9.2/bin/bundle:19:in `load'
    from /usr/ruby1.9.2/bin/bundle:19:in `<main>'
   FAILED: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler

!     Push failed: failed to install gems via Bundler
!     If the problem persists, see http://help.heroku.com and provide Request ID 6f60ac09-059f-4a33-b913-02e32e2f34e4.
```

Any idea how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nokogiri 1.6.5 is the latest release. It's likely the nokogiri dependencies and C libraries installed in the bamboo stack are not supported by newer versions of nokogiri. Don't forget that the bamboo stack is almost 4 years old.

You are pretending a library released less than a month ago to compile against C libraries released 4 years ago. The `wrong number of arguments` error it's likely to be caused by a change in the public method signature of one of the C libraries required by nokogiri. nokogiri is expecting the method to accept 3 parameters, whereas old version of the C library only accepts 2.

You can try to downgrade your nokogiri requirement to an older version.

```
gem 'nokogiri', '~> 1.4.0'
```

Indeed, the best solution would be to upgrade to the Cedar stack. You will eventually need in any case, the Bamboo stack will be retired in a few months and your app will stop working in any case.